# ASP.NET MVC Razor syntax: Customizable .cshtml page with c# code

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC / angularJS project which consists in a page builder. The user has the ability to create pages in a constructor.

When the page is saved, the constructor (which is all build in angularJS) saves a physical .cshtml page in the website directory The page only have plain HTML syntax.

Right now, we have some requirements to add some validation on these pages created using the constructor. The problem is, need to right it using razor syntax. @{ ViewBag.... }

I tried to write some razor c# code on this files, using just the notepad and when I open it in the browser, it renders as plain text. If I write the same code block in visual studio, it renders normally.

Maybe I'm missing something, but it is possible to do this? Or .cshtml pages can only "work" if they are edited and compiled?

**UPDATE**
I have found that to "render" the pages created, they've used this:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.htmlString)
```

This outputs the page as HTML. That's why when I edited the .cshtml page and put razor code, it got rendered as string.

Reformulating my question now: Is there a way to render an html string that contains razor code? Something like:

```
@{
   var login = ... ;
}
<div>@login</div>
```

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. What's the orginal issue (which led you to the conclusion that dynamically coding your own views was the best solution)?

Comment: Just updated my question. Got more facts now.